# Reporting Services Linear Gauge Scale

Tags: ssrs-2008, dundas

I have set up a linear gauge in Reporting Services 2008. What I would like to do is specify my scale interval. The only problem with this is the scale intervals I would like to use are not at constant intervals.

For example, say the scale min is $0 and the scale max is $10 000. Depending on the chart I may want an interval marker labelled at $2000, $5000, then $7945.

These numbers would be calculated based on percentages of scale max specified in the dataset. I have not been able to figure out how I would go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, however there are other markers you can put on the gauge to indicate: start, range, max etc

e.g.
    !----[XXXXXX*XXXXXX]--!  X
-10......0......10......20......30

Where ! is the start and end of the range
[XX] is where the data lies
* is what you achieved
x was the target